# Least Square regreesion

Tags: statistics

I have 300 equation with only 7 variable. i need to calculate these 7 variable in a way that in all 300 equations it fits using least squares approach. how can i compute these variables?

Best Regards,
Mohsen

Answer (score 1):

First, describe your system as matrix multiplication
$$A{\bf x} = {\bf b}$$
where $A$ is a $300\times 7$ matrix, ${\bf x}$ is your $7\times 1$ vector of variables, and ${\bf b}$ is a $300\times 1$ vector. Let $A^T$ be the transpose of $A$. To find a least squares solution to $A{\bf x}={\bf b}$ you should solve the system
$$A^TA{\bf x} = A^T {\bf b}.$$